# wordpress theme customization is blank in admin

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I am having an issue that i have been unable figure out. The problem im having is when i login to wordpress admin and try ro customize the theme nothing displays besides the nav. I can edit pages, posts, basically do everything in The Admin except customize the theme. When i upload to a live server i dont have this issue. I'll attach a link to an image for visual reference.

I'm running wamp on windows 8 with wordpress 3.5.1. I added the plugin server buddy to check the setup and everyhing appears fine. Permissions were 755 and I temporarily set it to 777 to make sure wasn't that for any strange reason. One thing I notice with folders is if I look at properties read only is highlighted not checked and applying win't save the change. Could be because have them applied in advance security settings?

I have tried this with multiple themes all the same result.

Here is the screenshot.
http://i46.tinypic.com/qs0c2d.gif

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Managed to fix this issue by adding 'define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );' at the bottom just above 'require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');' inside the wp-config file

Comment: I had this same issue when using HTTPS protocol in the admin. We need to use HTTPS in the admin area, so I have not figured out a solution to this without turning HTTPS off. The Customize area works fine when not using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.  I was forcing SSL/HTTPS on the admin console as well.  I turned off HTTPS on the admin console (still in use for my shopping cart) and all is well.